# How to remove white screen before Splash screen React Native?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

I added a splash screen when booting the app using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen#examples.

But before launching the splash screen, I can see a white screen. I can change that screen's colour using styles.xml but cannot remove it. Can anyone help me to remove that I am new to react-native?